# Silverstripe 4 - Dropdown field error

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am trying to create a dropdown list (ss4.2) but I am missing something and I am not sure what. I have had success with other methods except the one I need. Would someone be able to help me figure out what I have missed?

```
<?php
namespace SilverStripe\Gallery;

use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;
use SilverStripe\Forms\FieldList;
use SilverStripe\Forms\DropdownField;
use SilverStripe\ORM\DBEnum;

class Album extends DataObject {

private static $db = [
   'AlbumType' => 'Enum(array("Type1","type2","Type3"), "Type1")',
];

private static $table_name = 'AlbumCoverPhoto';

public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = FieldList::create(
        DropdownField::create('AlbumType',
            'Album type',
            singleton('Album')->dbObject('AlbumType')->enumValues())
        );

        return $fields;
    }   
 }
```

Thanks.
Lyn

Answer (score 3):

This is just an issue with namespacing in this line:

```
singleton('Album')->dbObject('AlbumType')->enumValues())
```

The data object you're asking for is `Album`, whereas the class is inside the `SilverStripe\Gallery` namespace (side note, please don't use SilverStripe as the vendor in your PHP namespaces as it's reserved for core SilverStripe modules and code).

When referring to classes you should try to use `::class` notation, e.g.

```
singleton(Album::class)->dbObject('AlbumType')->enumValues()
```

You don't actually need to reference the class though, because you're inside the scope of that class anyway so you can use `$this` instead. Try this:

```
$this->dbObject('AlbumType')->enumValue()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining and for the advice for using namespace. I have made the changes and works perfect.

Comment: Hi again, I am going through my templates and just realized that the values rendered are numerical rather than the values specified in the array ["Type1","type2","Type3"]. It works great in the admin interface but have I missed something to render the selected value to the template? Is it not  $AlbumType ?